# If I charge my mobile from different charger what happens?

Tags: charging

My charger is lost so I am using a charger with an output of 5.5v and 0.6A. My real charger  gives an output of 5V and 0.7A. Will the other charger damage my phone?

Comment: That question does not raise the concern about the extra half Volt.

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not damage your phone. As long as it's a micro USB charger, it will be fine.

5.5V is fine, I've had success with 6 Volts from a homemade charger, and you won't meet voltages higher than 5.5V on a micro USB charger anyway. Extra Volts are dangerous, so it's good to be cautious but 5.5V will not do any harm.

The current rating (Amperes, A) does not count; if it's too low, the phone may charge slowly or not at all, but higher rated chargers will not do harm.

Comment: Hi, this is something I know nearly **nothing** about, and I was curious. Would a higher amperage not burn it out if it is too high, or is it regulated by the device? I'm just thinking out loud, the micro USB on Samsung devices looks like it was soldered in by a blind cat and I've seen devices burn out. So, the device being ok, the Volts/Amps don't matter?

Comment: Think of voltage as the force pushing the current in the wire. An extra half a Volt doesn't matter, the phone has an internal regulator which can cope with little higher voltages. Don't go much higher, though, (like 9V) as it can damage your phone.

Comment: Amperes mean how much current is flowing. The ampere rating written on your charger means how much current it can supply. Think of it as the tapwater: the force pushing the water out is constant, but if you only open the tap a little, only a little water flows. But if you keep opening the tap more, you'll hit a point where the water flow will not increase; this is the charger's amperage, or current rating. The more Amperes a charger can provide, the better - a phone will only draw as much current as it needs.

Comment: If anything, a too low current rating can be harmful, not for the phone but for the charger - it can overheat and malfunction.

Comment: So as a higher water pressure would tear your faucet off the wall, so would a higher voltage damage your phone; but plus half a Volt is not high enough to do harm. Extra amperes don't matter as it's a maximum they write; the actual current is determined by the phone (or how much it opens the tap). If it needs too much, it can overexcercise the charger, making it overheat, but the phone won't be damaged.

Comment: Excellent, many thanks for that! Very interesting to read, and something that is worth knowing. Much appreciated.